# Unable to compile class for JSP using Netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I'm getting the following error while I try to run my project in Netbeans. I have used JSP, Struts and JS in my project. So plz help me out.

**Error Log:**

```
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [33] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\mahesh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\apache-tomcat-7.0.41.0_base\work\Catalina\localhost\mypro\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: shared content of index.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the servletcontainer-specific libraries such as jsp-api.jar in your /WEB-INF/lib folder. These libraries supports older versions and the method was introduced in newer version(Servlet 2.5). Those libraries don't belong in the webapp's classpath.